# creating random button in Javascript from list of buttons

Tags: javascript, button, random

I am trying this simple JavaScript project for my Bootcamp pre work and it suggested making a new button and I decided to try and make a random button out of the buttons I had already created so that when you clicked it, it would run one of the scripts for the buttons that I have already defined. I have been working on this for a few hours and I just can't seem to get it or find another example of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px"

});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "50px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "50px"

});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue"

});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0.2"

});



document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style = "height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"

});

let btnList = ["#button1", "#button2", "#button3", "#button4", "#button5"];

const randomBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('rand');


randomBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * randomBtn.length)
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body onload="printBtn();">

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button class="rand" id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button2">Shrink</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button3">Blue</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button4">Fade</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button5">Reset</button>
    <button class="rand">Random</button>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try create a object with actions to use, you can share de actions with the random buttom, something like this.

```js
const buttonHandlers = {
  grow: function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px"
  },
  shrink: function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "50px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "50px"
  },
  blue: function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue"
  },
  fade: function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0.2"
  },
  reset: function () {
      document.getElementById("box").style = "height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"
  },
  random: function() {
    const btnList = ["grow", "shrink", "blue", "fade", "reset"];
    const randomAction = Math.floor(Math.random() * btnList.length);

    buttonHandlers[btnList[randomAction]]();

  }
}

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", buttonHandlers.grow);
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", buttonHandlers.shrink);
document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", buttonHandlers.blue);
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", buttonHandlers.fade);
document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", buttonHandlers.reset);
document.getElementById('random').addEventListener("click", buttonHandlers.random);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body onload="">

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button class="rand" id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button2">Shrink</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button3">Blue</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button4">Fade</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button5">Reset</button>
    <button class="rand" id ="random" >Random</button>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Greats.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in the fact that since you are getting `randomBtn` using `getElementsByClassName` it is in fact an array of elements instead of a single element. So it is invalid to call `addEventListener` on an array.

Instead, what you should do is consider the random button to be an individual button and use it to trigger the `click` event on other buttons. This will make sure your changes remain encapsulated within individual buttons. You also don't have to maintain a hardcoded list of button IDs since you are already following a pretty straightforward convention of sequential button numbers.

In the code below, I've connected the random button to the first 4 buttons (didn't think 'reset' would be fun in the random button).

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px"
});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "50px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "50px"
});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue"
});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0.2"
});


document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style = "height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"
});

const randomButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("rand");

document.getElementById('rand').addEventListener("click", function () {
    let buttonNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * randomButtons.length);
    console.log(`Button number: ${buttonNumber}`);
    document.getElementById(`button${buttonNumber}`).click();
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body onload="">

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button class="rand" id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button2">Shrink</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button3">Blue</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button4">Fade</button>
    <button id="button5">Reset</button>
    <button id="rand">Random</button>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px"

});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "50px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "50px"

});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue"

});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0.2"

});



document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", function () {

    document.getElementById("box").style = "height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"

});

let btnList = ["#button1", "#button2", "#button3", "#button4", "#button5"];


const randomBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('rand')[5];

randomBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   
let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)

switch(idx) {
  case 0:
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px"
    break;
  case 1:
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "50px"
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = "50px"
    break;
   case 2:
     document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    break;
  case 3:
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0.2"
    break;
  case 4:
     document.getElementById("box").style = "height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"

    break;
  default:
    // code block
}




})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body >

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button class="rand" id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button2">Shrink</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button3">Blue</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button4">Fade</button>
    <button class="rand" id="button5">Reset</button>
    <button class="rand">Random</button>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```